# How to convert string to hash table in perl

Tags: string, perl, hash

I have a string from a for loop:

```
@file = "/path/window/*_testing_42.csv";


foreach $file(@file) {


$name = $file=~ /(\w*)_testing_42/; #comes from file path
$name = 1$;
print $name; #prints G43B76P90T45

}
```

There are 4 values I am I need from this string (G43, B76, P90, T45). I want to place these into a hash so that I can refer to each value specifically. However the hash table code I am trying to implement is not working for my intended purpose:

```
 my %hash;



foreach $file(@file) {


    $name = $file=~ /(\w*)_testing_42/; #comes from file path
    $name = 1$;
    print $name; #prints G43B76P90T45



    my($first $second $third $fourth) = $name;
    $hash{"first"} = $first;
    $hash{"second"} = $second;
    $hash{"third"} = $third;
    $hash{"fourth"} = $fourth;
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
    print $fourth; #should print T45


    print $first; #should print G43
    print $third #should print  P90
}
```

Comment: The posted code is incorrect Perl, which can't run (even if it were complete) and won't produce what code comments show.  Can you post your actual code?  That helps a lot in helping you out.

Comment: Also I'm unclear whether you're wanting to do a pattern match against the names of the files in `@files`, or do you want to open the files, read lines of data from them and match against those lines? It would be helpful if you could provide examples of the filenames if that's what you're matching, or examples of file contents.

Comment: @zdim Code was edited/updated... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @GrantMcLean I just want to be able to put the four string values from the string ($name) into a seperate hash key values. I updated the code for the filename. It is globbed so it has multiple values...

Comment: To break the string `'G43B76P90T45'`  into "letter-numbers" patterns (the goal I assume from the question): `my @parts = 'G43B76P90T45' =~ /([a-zA-Z][0-9]+)/g;` But the code shown in the question is "Illegal" with many basic syntax errors and I can't tell whether the above will actually work in your real code.  Just once more: please show us your actual code :)

Comment: When you say you want 4 values from the name, is it the exact 4 values you listed? Or is it 'G' followed by a 2 digit number, 'B' followed by a 2 digit number etc? Some more examples of filenames you're matching and expected output would help.

Comment: @GrantMcLean it is the exact 4 values I listed. I updated my expected output

Comment: I'm still failing to understand something.  If every file had those exact 4 values followed by `_testing_42` then every file would have the exact same name. Are you trying to match filenames that contain _some_ of those values and then use the hash to determine which values are present?

Comment: @GrantMcLean The problem is those 4 values are arbitrary, one week they may be those names (G43, B76, P90, T45), one week they may be COMPLETELY different names. Therefore, I do not want to assume or hardcode their names at all in the code, I just want to grab the names that are being globbed, place them in a string, and then make that string into a hash table that points to the 4 strings, so I may access those strings individually by key ( 1 => G43, 2=> B76 etc... ).

Comment: It seems like I'm inching closer to understanding. When you say they could be completely different the next week, would the four parts you're interested in always be exactly 3 characters long? Or is there some other way you can look at a filename and recognise the values of the four parts?

Comment: @GrantMcLean Yes. The four parts would always be 3 characters long. However, there could be 6 values, or 2 values, or 1 value in a different week. But the format of the value will remain the same, yes.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to split the name in 4 parts:

```
my ($first, $second, $third, $fourth) = unpack("(A3)*", $name);
```

Fill the hash

```
$hash{"first"} = $first;
$hash{"second"} = $second;
$hash{"third"} = $third;
$hash{"fourth"} = $fourth;
```

and print the hash

```
print $hash{"fourth"};
```

Comment: This assumes that patterns to extract are always three characters long; I'd state that assumption. (Also, to nitpick: it does "_print the hash_", it prints one element of it.)

Comment: Simplifies to: `my %hash; @hash{qw( first second third fourth )} = unpack('(A3)*', $name);`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then @Gever's answer should do the trick.  Here's an alternative implementation using regexes rather than unpack:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file = glob("/path/window/*_testing_42.csv");

foreach my $file (@file) {
    my($name) = $file =~ /(\w+)_testing_42/;
    my @code = $name =~ /(...)/g;
    say 'Parts found: ', scalar(@code);   # Parts found: 4
    say $code[0];   # G43
    say $code[1];   # B76
    say $code[2];   # P90
    say $code[3];   # T45
}
```

I used an array rather than a hash, because that makes more sense to me, but if you really want a hash, you could do it like this:

```
foreach my $file (@file) {
    my($name) = $file =~ /(\w+)_testing_42/;
    my %hash;
    @hash{'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'} = $name =~ /(...)/g;
    say $hash{first};   # G43
    say $hash{second};  # B76
    say $hash{third};   # P90
    say $hash{fourth};  # T45
}
```

In this line:

```
my($name) = $file =~ /(\w+)_testing_42/;
```

The parentheses around `$name` are important because they force the match to be evaluated in list context, which returns the parts of the regex that were captured in the `(\w+)`.  Without the parentheses, the value 1 would be assigned to `$name` because there was 1 match.

The syntax for assigning a list of values to a series of keys in a hash (called a 'hash slice') is somewhat confusing.  Perl knows we're assigning values into `%hash` because of the `{` after the variable name, but we put a `@` before the variable name to indicate we're assigning multiple values to a hash slice.  Using a `$` before the variable name would indicate we're assigning to a single value in the hash.

The other thing I changed from your code is that I declared `%hash` inside the loop.  Which means that you can only refer to it inside the loop.  If you declare it outside the loop, one set of values will persist after each matching filename has been processed, but the hash might contain values from different filenames depending on how many fields were present on the last iterations.

Comment: I used `(...)` as a simple way to match any 3 characters.  But yes, you could also write it as `(.{3})` or `([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})` or even `(\w{3})` which is letters, number and the `_` underscore (i.e.: characters that are valid in a Perl variable/identifier name).